# how do we give authors names and affiliations details in biblatex package

Tags: biblatex

I am making a research article using latex file. For that I want to display the bibliography in author-year order and also I need to mention the citations with author and year (if more than two authors then i need to give et.al). For that I used the following format:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=2]{biblatex} % newly added
%\usepackage[style=authoryear,sortcites,sorting=ynt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{wassenberg},\parencite{cicero},\parencite{companion},\parencite{angenendt}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So it is working but when i am giving the title for document along with authors and affiliations information it is not working ... it is giving the errors. And also i need the packages to display the figures which are in `.eps` format.

Hence I request you to provide any suggestions and answers how to resolve the above need so that i am very grateful if I got the above to you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I've edited your question to indent the code, and because (so long as you use `biblatex-examples.bib` you shouldn't need the `.bib` file, as this is a standard file. But I suspect your problem isn't with `biblatex` at all, but with `\maketitle` and how to include graphics. You probably need to clarify the question. Can you post the code that doesn't work, and explain exactly what's wrong. If you have questions about different topics it will be better to post them separately.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Could you please specify your problem in greater detail? It would be helpful to see the code that causes the trouble. The code above naturally compiles fine. Also, the question about `.eps` graphics seems an entirely unrelated one, better split that up into a new question.